# Worklight 6.2: Successful sent tag push notification but not received at android devices

Tags: android, push-notification, tags, ibm-mobilefirst

Im having issues to receive push notification on android devices.  I am using tag based notification using Worklight 6.2. Below is the steps used to create the apps.

1. Create hybrid apps
2. Import the example into Eclipse
3. Create new environment (Android)
4. Create a new project in GCM and get the required credentials (server key)
5. key in App ID(project no) and api key(server key) in application-descriptor.xml file
6. Run all environment.
7. Create the .apk files and import into android devices.
8. Run Android emulator using API19 Google Apis.
9. Successfully subscribe to event tag
10. Invoke adapter procedur (sendTagNotification)

After invoke adapter procedure, I did check the logcat and no errors found. Can anyone help me. Below is the snippet of logcat after i invoke the procedure.

01-14 05:28:31.153: D/HttpPostRequestSender(1951): HttpPostRequestSender.run in HttpPostRequestSender.java:46 :: Sending request https://amrs.malaysiaairports.com.my:444/SimpleProject/apps/services/api/SimpleProject/android/heartbeat 01-14 05:28:32.193: D/NONE(1951): response [https://amrs.malaysiaairports.com.my:444/SimpleProject/apps/services/api/SimpleProject/android/heartbeat] success:

Thanks!

Comment: Post the 
a) adapter code you are using to send out the notification
b) the server side log
c) the complete log cat

Comment: its solved already. I forgot 1 step to build for worklight environment. After I build to Worklight environment, its done. :)

Comment: Why not write this as answer? Please do not keep questions unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

> its solved already. I forgot 1 step to build for worklight environment. After I build to Worklight environment, its done. :)